# WPF - GridView, selecting the row automatically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've a GridView with this structure:

```
<GridView>
    <GridViewColumn Header="Data" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path = Score}"/>
</GridView>
```

Now all of the items are inside an observable collection, I want check if the value of the row is changed and then select the row automatically behind code. Actually I already defined the condition but I can't manage to select the item changed behind code to GridView, someone know how?

Answer (score 1):

you should use the SelectedItem property in your DataGrid or ListView

```
 SelectedItem="{Binding Path=YourSelectedItem}"
```

Comment: is possible remove the item selected after 10 seconds?

Comment: Of course it is possible. When a selection changed, start a timer with tick =  10 sn, delete the selected object from your observable collection and your done

Answer (score 1):

If you bind the grid with an `observablecollection` then I think you can make use of `CollectionChanged` event to detect if collection/data changed.

Here is an example:

```
/// <summary>
/// The collection of drivers just changed: add or remove
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender">Sernder of the Event.</param>
/// <param name="e">Event Arguments.</param>
private void Drivers_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Only Delete
    if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
    {
        foreach (FormulaOneDriver driver in e.OldItems)
        {
            driver.Delete();
        }
    }
}
```

To use it register the event in constructor.

```
ObservableCollection<FormulaOneDriver> drivers = this.DriversDataGrid.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<FormulaOneDriver>;
drivers.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(this.Drivers_CollectionChanged);
```

Comment: is possible change the color of the selected item?